# Firebase Cloud Storage getSignedUrl expiration date cannot be in the past (Firebase Cloud Functions)

Tags: node.js, datetime, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

This is my cloud functions code snippet relevant to the problem:

```
// Somewhere outside the function
import * as nodedt from 'node-datetime'
...

// Inside the function trigger
const dt = nodedt.create((new Date()).valueOf() + 300000)
const exp = dt.format("d-m-Y H:M:S")

return bucket.file(MY_FILE_PATH).getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: exp
})
.then(signedUrl => console.log(`Signed url: ${signedUrl} retrieved.`))
.then(error => console.log(`Failed to retrieve signed url: ${error}`))
```

The output in functions logs is:

> Oct 9, 2017
>
> 1:17:43.087 AM
>   outlined_flag
>   FUNCTIONS_NAME
>   Function execution took 2353 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
>
> 1:17:43.075 AM
>   info
>   FUNCTIONS_NAME
>   Failed to retrieve signed url: Error: An expiration date cannot be in the past.
>
> 1:17:43.068 AM
>   info
>   FUNCTIONS_NAME
>   Fetching signed url which expires at 08-10-2017 18:22:43. Current time 08-10-2017 18:17:43

It's weird because in the log, when i print out expiration date and current date, it's clear that the expiration date is not in the past (they differ for about 5 mins, as intended)

My initial analysis is because the time in Firebase Server is different with my timezone (mine is GMT+7. Notice that the log date is Oct 9, 2017, and the logs message is Oct 8, 2017). **If so, then how to sync the timezone?** I don't really care which timezone used, since all I wanted is just **5 mins expiration time**, and the `expires` field in `getSignedUrl()` parameter **can't** be formatted in millisecond value. (Tried it, and it's printed as `NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN:NaN`)

**So, is there any solution for this? And how to do it? Thanks**

P.S. Idk if this is relevant: I need the signed url to be passed into kraken.io API to do image-optimization, thumbnail-creation, and EXIF-based auto-rotation). The other options than using signed url is by downloading the image first to `os.tmpdir()` folder, and provide the link to that file in tmp, and call `fs.unlinkSync()` after the process has been completed. **But idk how to get the url link if the image is in the `os.tmpdir()` folder.**

Answer (score 3):

Well it turns out that it need to be in month-day-year format.

For example

> 01-04-2017 for Apr 4th, 2017

and what I did:

> 01-04-2017 for Jan 1st, 2017

Comment: You can also specify the expiry time as a UNIX time format, i.e. seconds after the epoch. For example, for a five minute expiry, you could use `Date.now() + 5 * 60 * 1000`

Comment: More precisely, the value passed on the config object, is passed to the Javascript `Date()` constructor. Its one argument version expects milliseconds after the epoch. The underlying Google endpoint expects *seconds* after the epoch, a conversion which the Node.js Client API performs.

Answer (score 3):

This error may also happen when setting a date on a variable and this variable persist after its expiration date:

```js
const signedUrlOptions = { // stale options persist even after expiration date
  action: "read",
  expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10, // invalid date after ten minutes pass
};

const fetchImageUrls = async () => {
  const [signedUrl] = await storage.bucket().file("filename").getSignedUrl(signedUrlOptions);
  return signedUrl;
};
```

In the example you need to make sure to create "fresh" options with a date that is not expired:

```js
const fetchImageUrls = async () => {

  const signedUrlOptions = { // create fresh options here when calling the function
    action: "read",
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10, // always a valid date now
  };

  const [signedUrl] = await storage.bucket().file("filename").getSignedUrl(signedUrlOptions);
  return signedUrl;
};
```